# As funções não terminam

Tags: java, thread

Após a execução das 4 funções ele deveria imprimir o tempo que demorou para executar

```
public class main 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    long init  = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    ataque1();
    ataque2();
    ataque3();
    ataque4();
    long end  = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    long diff = end - init;
    System.out.print("Demorou " + (diff / 1000) + " segundos");
}

static int for1 = 0;
static int for2 = 20 / 4;
static int for3 = for2 + for2;
static int for4 = for2 = for3;

public static void ataque1()
{
    new Thread() 
    { 
        @Override 
        public void run() 
        {
            int for11 = for1;
            int for22 = for2;
            int for33 = for3;
            int for44 = for4;

            for(int i = for1 ; i <= for2; i++)
            {
                /*if(i == busca)
                {
                    break;
                }*/

                System.out.println(i + " de 999999"); 
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
public static void ataque2()
{
    new Thread() 
    { 
        @Override 
        public void run() 
        {
            int for11 = for1;
            int for22 = for2;
            int for33 = for3;
            int for44 = for4;

            for(int i = for2; i <= for3; i++)
            {
                /*if(i == busca)
                {
                    break;
                }*/

                System.out.println(i + " de 999999"); 
            }
        }
    }.start();

}
public static void ataque3()
{
    new Thread() 
    { 
        @Override 
        public void run() 
        {
            int for11 = for1;
            int for22 = for2;
            int for33 = for3;
            int for44 = for4;

            for(int i = for3; i <= for4; i++)
            {
                /*if(i == busca)
                {
                    break;
                }*/

                System.out.println(i + " de 999999"); 
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
public static void ataque4()
{
    new Thread() 
    { 
        @Override 
        public void run() 
        {
            int for11 = for1;
            int for22 = for2;
            int for33 = for3;
            int for44 = for4;
            for(int i = for4; i <= 20; i++)
            {
                /*if(i == busca)
                {
                    break;
                }*/

                System.out.println(i + " de 999999"); 
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Porem aparece o tempo que demorou no meio da execução ao invés do final

```
0 de 999999
1 de 999999
2 de 999999
3 de 999999
4 de 999999
5 de 999999
6 de 999999
7 de 999999
8 de 999999
9 de 999999
Demorou 0 segundos10 de 999999
11 de 999999
12 de 999999
13 de 999999
14 de 999999
15 de 999999
16 de 999999
17 de 999999
18 de 999999
19 de 999999
20 de 999999
```

Comment: O que essa linha está fazendo? `static int for4 = for2 = for3;` Você quer que o valor de `for4` seja igual de `for2` e igual a `for3`, que por sua vez é `10`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu programa está iniciando 4 threads, e não está esperando que eles terminem a sua execução antes de imprimir o tempo - o que é exatamente o que ele está fazendo. Se você quiser realmente calcular o tempo, você precisa esperar que os threads terminem, por exemplo, chamando a função [`Thread.join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()).

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    long init  = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    Thread t1 = ataque1();
    Thread t2 = ataque2();
    Thread t3 = ataque3();
    Thread t4 = ataque4();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
    long end  = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    long diff = end - init;
    System.out.print("Demorou " + (diff / 1000) + " segundos");
}

public static Thread ataque1()
{
    Thread t = new Thread()
    {
        // implementação
    };
    t.start();
    return t;
}
// O mesmo para ataque[2-4]
```

Comment: Não é possível dar join dessa forma. oque devo fazer ??

Comment: +1 porém você precisa usar o `join` no `Thread` em si e não na função como esse código está fazendo. Sugiro que cada função retorne o `Thread` criado, e este seja guardado numa variável.

Comment: @mgibsonbr correto, o join precisa ser dado no Thread e não na função. Editei a minha resposta, obrigado!

Comment: Funcionou certinho, mas poderia me dizer oque o ".join()" faz exatamente ??

Comment: Quando você chama `join` em um objeto da classe `Thread`, a execução do seu thread para até que aquele thread termine sua execução. Olhe a documentação em http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join() para maiores informações.

Comment: Mas mesmo todos os thread com "join" eles vão executar em paralelo né ??

Comment: Isso. A chamada a `thread.start()` faz com que o thread inicie a sua execução, e eles continuam executando (concorrentemente) até que terminem.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução mais elegante seria com uso de [ThreadGroup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html).

*Segue exemplo:*

```
//adicionado Grupo
static ThreadGroup tg; 

public static void main(String[] args) {
   // instancia de grupo de threads - ataque
    tg = new ThreadGroup("ataque");

    long init = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ataque1();
    ataque2();
    ataque3();
    ataque4();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long diff = end - init;

    // obtem threads ativas do grupo
    Thread[] thds = new Thread[tg.activeCount()];
    int nthds = tg.enumerate(thds);
    // aguarda todas do grupo para continuar
    for (int i = 0; i < nthds; i++) {
            thds[i].join();
    }

    System.out.print("Demorou " + (diff / 1000) + " segundos");
}

public static void ataque1() {
    // declaração de grupo e nome da thread
    new Thread(tg, "ataque1") {
    // prossegue até ataque4 ...
```